# Add new field of normally distributed random values to dataframe

Tags: r

I'm trying to add a field to my dataframe and populate it with random normally distributed values ranging from 10 to 50 with a mean of 25.  Also I only want to populate 35% of the rows in the new field and leave the rest empty.  I want the new generated values to be randomly distributed throughout the rows in the new field.  I was thinking about using something like mapply with randnorm.  Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want a lot of things. What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

The exact range is tricky as you want both a normal distribution and a mean that is not in the middle of the values. This gets you there, approximately:

with data frame `df`

```
 n <- nrow(df)
 x <- rnorm(n, mean=25, sd=8)
 x[x<10] <- NA
 x[x>50] <- NA

 isna <- sum(is.na(x))
 i <- sample(n, 0.65 * (n-isna))
 x[i] <- NA
 df$x <- x
```